# Copy constructor called for captured variable instead of move constructor

Tags: c++11, lambda, move-semantics

When compiled with gcc 4.7.2 or 4.8.1 and run the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
    }
    A(const A& a)
    {
        printf("Copy ctor\n");
    }
    A(A&& a)
    {
        printf("Move ctor\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto func = [a] {
    };

    auto newfunc = std::move(func);
    return 0;
}
```

will give the output:

```
Copy ctor
Move ctor
```

which seems to be perfectly normal.

However, when `A a;` is changed to `const A a;`, the output is as follows:

```
Copy ctor
Copy ctor
```

Why is the move of lambda affected by the fact whether the original variable has been const or not?

FWIW, MSVC2012 always makes two copies.

Comment: constness can't be dropped automatically. By adding it, the capturing lambda must store it as const and you can't move from const.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan that's close but not exactly correct, as you can see from my example you can overload the move constructor with `const A&&`

Comment: @aaronman You are right of course. I somehow thought the signature asked for non-const rvalue-references specfically.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan you are correct in the sense that moving from a const object is inherently weird because you can't "move" anything out of the const object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not have a `const A&&` for your move constructor it will not be called. Since a move generally sets an object to it's default value you often cannot move from a const object.

Keep in mind a if the move constructor is overloaded correctly the object will be moved. For example try running this version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <functional>                                                              

class A                                                                            
{                                                                                  
public:                                                                            
    A()                                                                            
    {                                                                              
    }                                                                              
    A(const A& a)                                                                  
    {                                                                              
        printf("Copy ctor\n");                                                     
    }                                                                              
    A(const A&& a)                                                                 
    {                                                                              
        printf("Move ctor\n");                                                     
    }                                                                              
};                                                                                 

int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    const A a;                                                                     
    auto func = [a] {                                                              
    };                                                                             

    const auto newfunc = std::move(func);                                          
    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

Run this code and you will noticed that the object is moved wether there is a `const` qualification or not.

Comment: Thank you, today I learned about const rvalue references :-) But my question is: does the constness of the `a` variable concern the type of variable inside lambda?

Comment: @OlegAndreev well it has to be stored somewhere right, of course to really know you would have so know a bit more about lamb dad implementation

Comment: @OlegAndreev btw I know you don't have enough rep to upvote but if my answer helped you, you can still accept it